# Redirect script is not working in Wordpress header

Tags: javascript, wordpress, redirect

I'm looking for a way to automatically redirect the user to a different URL for mobile users. I think the solution to this is to simply check the screen resolution and redirect on mobile.

I found the code below as a solution on the internet but when I add this to my Wordpress header it doesn't work. How can I add this to Wordpress site?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 950) {
    window.location = "https://www.google.com/";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wordpress template hierarchy means that you can have different header template files, so you might not be adding this to the one that is in use - or even if you are, you would need to add it to all of the header files so that it gets added for every page.

Instead, you can use a function in your functions.php to add the script into the `head` on every page. Add the following anywhere in your theme's **functions.php**:

```
function add_redirect_js_to_head() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (screen.width <= 950) {
            window.location = "https://www.example.com/";
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_redirect_js_to_head');
```

Note that the `wp_head` is theme-dependent, however it is widely supported so this should work in any well developed theme.

> Although this is theme-dependent, it is one of the most essential theme hooks, so it is widely supported. See the Plugin API Hooks page on the Theme handbook for more information.

Reference: [WP Code Reference for wp_head hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/)

Comment: Thank you in advance. When I add the code to the functions.php file, it didn't work, but I installed the Code Snippets plugin, added this function and it works. I don't know exactly where the plugin added this script. Thank you again for your effort.